# Bootstrap Modal on dynamically generated link

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap 3. I clicked on a link which generates two different link. Each of them calls bootstrap modal on its click & their contents are loaded from two different files 'content.html' & 'content2.html'. Both have different content. When I click on first link, it shows correct content while when I click on second link it again shows content from first remote url.

The live demo can be found at http://myraipur.com/so/test.html

Here is my code.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" >
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">     </script>


<center><a href="#" id="generate">Launch demo modal</a></center>

<div id="load" ></div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
     <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#generate').on('click',function(){
    $('#load').html('<a href="content.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Click Me</a> <a href="content2.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Click2 Me</a>');
});

  $("#myModal").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
    var link = $(e.relatedTarget);
    console.log(link.attr("href"));
    $(this).find(".md-body").load(link.attr("href"));
  });
});
</script>
```